# Turning String into File or vice versa in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a little question I have been banging my head on for a few days.

```
void _loadImage() async {
SharedPreferences saveImage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
setState(() {
  if (_imagepath == null) {
    _imagepath = MemoryImage(kTransparentImage);
  }else{
    _imagepath = saveImage.getString('imagepath');
  }
});
```

}

So I have this function to save the image to shared preferences, but would like for if else check before it executes that if the path (which is a string) is null, it turns to transparent, and if not, to just regular path. This syntax obviously doesn't work since the String doesn't equal to File:

```
_imagepath = MemoryImage(kTransparentImage);
```

Where the _imagepath is a String (a path) and the MemoryImage is a File.

Is there a simple solution to make this work within a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it in this function then you can do it like this:

```dart
  ImageProvider _image;

  void _loadImage() async {
    SharedPreferences saveImage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      if (_image == null) {
        _image = MemoryImage(kTransparentImage);
      } else {
        var path = saveImage.getString('imagepath');
        var file = File(path);
        _image = FileImage(file);
      }
    });
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Image(image: _image);
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Not necessarily within a function, but I thought it would be neater.